# SQL - SELECT statement syntax

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, select

In a select statement to open a flat file on my desktop, I used the following code, but it failed.

```
SELECT * FROM C:\Users\MikeAD\Desktop\DistributionFile.txt
```

Does anyone know the correct syntax for this?

I also tried

```
  SELECT * FROM OPENDATASOURCE( 
           'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 
           'Data Source=C:\Users\MikeAD\Desktop\DistributionFile.txt)
```

Comment: Any errors? Try to use  'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' as provider

Comment: Do you have ad hoc queries enabled on the server?  Post the error message you get.

Comment: Failed how? Describe in detail what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the following query:

```
select * 
from OpenDataSource( 'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0',
'Data Source=C:\Users\MikeAD\Desktop;Extended Properties="Text;HDR=YES;"',
'select * from DistributionFile.txt')
```

or

```
select * from OpenDataSource('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
'Text;Database=C:\Users\MikeAD\Desktop\;HDR=YES')...[DistributionFile#txt]
```

Also see the article [Connect to Text Files with the Microsoft Jet ODBC Text Driver
by Steve Kass](http://www.users.drew.edu/skass/sql/TextDriver.htm)

Comment: The first one did not run. It showed incorrect syntax error. The second gave this error: The OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" has not been rejistered

Comment: Ok, try to use `Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0` in second query. I can not know which providers have already installed

Comment: Thanks. I am getting closer. I got this error: OLE DB provider 'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' cannot be used for distributed queries because the provider is configured to run in single-threaded apartment mode.

Answer (score 0):

In this way, normally, I can select form text files:

```
select *
from openrowset('MSDASQL'
               ,'Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)}'
               ,'select * from C:\Temp\test1.CSV')
```

In order to get this working, you have to enable adhoc distributed query as follow:
[ad hoc distributed queries Server Configuration Option](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187569.aspx)
Let me know

Giova

Comment: I got this error: 
Msg 15281, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
SQL Server blocked access to STATEMENT 'OpenRowset/OpenDatasource' of component 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries'
because this component is turned off as part of the security configuration for this server. A system administrator can 
enable the use of 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries' by using sp_configure. For more information about enabling 'Ad Hoc Distributed 
Queries', see "Surface Area Configuration" in SQL Server Books Online.

Comment: @ObserveDBA: I added my response. Regards Giova

Comment: Do you mean the ad-hoc  distributed queries?. If that is so, I am not sure where to access that option

Comment: I went to the link, but still getting errors  with the second 'sp_configure'

Comment: Maybe are you using sql server 2005?